# CakePHP: Unable to load class from custom package

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

We want to use the FPDF library in one of our controllers.

We created the following files:

```
app
-Lib
--Fpdf
---files.php
---fpdf.php
---fdpf_wrapper.php <-- this is our class (FdpfWrapper) which extends the base FPDF class
```

Right before the controller class, we try this:

```
App::uses('FpdfWrapper', 'Lib/Fpdf');
```

But it fails every time. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the file `fdpf_wrapper.php` to `FpdfWrapper.php` and try with just `App::uses('FpdfWrapper', 'Lib');`? Also, I'm sure you've read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450519/cakephp-i-cant-get-appuses-to-find-my-class), but couldn't it be an error with the file (syntax, logic, etc) instead of cakephp not finding the class? If that doesn't work, can you be more specific and tell *what* fails everytime and how? `Class not found error` or something else?

Comment: @Nunser it was a class not found error. We're currently getting it to work with `App::import('Vendor', bla bla);`. Not sure whether Vendor or Lib is the most appropriate place for this.

Comment: It just depends if it's a third party library or not ([doc reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html#the-app-folder)). Is it? and changing the name of the file to what I pointed out did not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, package paths must be registered in order to be used with [`App::uses`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App%3a%3auses), and `Lib/Fpdf` is no such one, by default only the core packages are registered.

You could either extend the paths for an already existing package, in your case that would be `Lib`:

```
App::build(array('Lib' => array(APP . 'Lib' . DS . 'Fpdf' . DS)));
```

And then use `App::uses('FpdfWrapper', 'Lib');`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#adding-paths-for-app-to-find-packages-in

or better add a new package:

```
App::build(array('Lib/Fpdf' => array(APP . 'Lib' . DS . 'Fpdf' . DS)), App::REGISTER);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#add-new-packages-to-an-application

Then you can use `App::uses('FpdfWrapper', 'Lib/Fpdf');`

And last but not least, of course the filename must follow the CakePHP conventions as already mentioned by @Nunser, ie `fdpf_wrapper.php` must be renamed to `FdpfWrapper.php`

Answer (score 2):

My case was a bit different.

To make `App::uses('ExampleAPI', 'ExampleAPI')` work make sure that:

- `/Lib/ExampleAPI/ExampleAPI.php` exists and is readable
- `/Lib/ExampleAPI/ExampleAPI.php` contains `class ExampleAPI{}` declaration
- you call `new ExampleAPI` in the referring code