# CakePHP FacebookSession class not found issue

Tags: cakephp, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying use Facebook lib v4 to create a simple Facebook login.

I'm following Facebook guide and I'm stucked at begnning, CakePHP is not finding FacebookSession class, follow below the facts:

FacebookSession class path:

```
App/Lib/Facebook/src/Facebook
```

Use in Controller:

```
app::uses('FacebookSession', 'Facebook/src/Facebook');
```

I think the Issue is in this specific Facebook Lib because I'm using WideImage class and I'm applying the same logic to use the Class and is working Perfectly.

For the record I'm using PHP 5.4

Comment: Lowercase `app`, missing quotes, I kinda doubt that this is how your actual code looks like... ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version too!

Comment: I've edited, but i can say that path mispelled is not the issue, i checked thousand times.

Answer (score 6):

### Custom paths/packages need to be registered

First of all that's not how `App::uses()` works. Custom paths/packages need to be registered first, please refer to **[CakePHP: Unable to load class from custom package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120409/cakephp-unable-to-load-class-from-app-lib)**

Also the `Lib` folder is ment to hold 1st party libraries, 3rd party libraries like the Facebook SDK should go into the `Vendor` folder.

See also **[Cookbook > CakePHP Folder Structure](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html)**

### Use composer or the autoloader that ships with the SDK

In case you can't/don't want to use [**the recommended way of including the SDK**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0), that is by installing it using composer (make sure you read the notes in **[Installing CakePHP with Composer](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html)** when using composer), then you have to make sure that you include the `autoload.php` file that ships with the SDK, which should be as simple as requiring it in your bootstrap

```
require_once APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Facebook' . DS . 'autoload.php';
```

From there on you should be able to use the SDK classes [**as shown in the docs**](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/#usage).

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID','YOUR_APP_SECRET');

$session = new FacebookSession('access-token');
```

Comment: You give a lot of options, I need just one that works. I dont use composer, i'd prefer a way that dont use composer. I moved the folder to vendor and tryed this: 
App::build(array('Vendor' => array(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Facebook' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'Facebook')));
App::uses('FacebookSession', 'Vendor');

Still dont working

Comment: Well, I don't think two are _that_ many options. If you don't want to use composer, then user the second option, include the SDK's autoloader in your bootstrap, all you have to do is copy & paste that one single line. @DanielFaria

Comment: Worked, but I puted require_once APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'Facebook' . DS . 'autoload.php'; inside the Controller that I'm using the SDK even bootstrap.. Is there a problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "_...even bootstrap_". However, in case you are only using the SDK in that specific controller, then there shouldn't be any problems with including the SDK only there. @DanielFaria