# Facebook PHP SDK 4.x and Cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp

I'm having problem integrating Facebook PHP SDK in CakePHP. I've googled a lot and I'm only finding guides from some years ago, referring to the class Facebook(.php). This class appears to not exist anymore.

I want to simply use Facebook login together with CakePHP Auth. My head is all blurry atm :S

Can someone help me set everything up?

For instance, I've tried stuff like:

```
App::import('Vendor", "facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook');
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('ID#', 'SECRET#');
```

The above didn't work.

It was a while ago I used cakephp and I'm pretty rusty atm. Please help me out anyone! :)

**I finally loaded the Facebook SDK into my AppController**

**Updated problem:**

The problem that I had with the Facebook Plugin from nick as well is that when I click the facebook generated Login-link, the screen becomes blank :S facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=... $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("google.com"); Shouldn't that do something when I click the link from $helper->getLoginUrl() ?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but it covers your problem: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743655/cakephp-facebooksession-class-not-found-issue/24746915** ps, "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin for easier implementation

Comment: I've tried to use that one. When I click on the Facebook Login-button the page I come to is blank. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: You can create your own login url using App::uses('FB', 'Facebook.Lib'); FB::getLoginUrl(); then,  FB::api('/me'); to get logged in user's login.

Comment: Where should I put the SDK Abhishek? How do I use it like that?

Comment: app/Plugin/Facebook put plugin code here , it has same FB php sdk(v 3.2.1) in lib folder .
For more info you can go over [Install and Setup](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin#install-and-setup)

Comment: I got it to work using the Facebook SDK. One problem that I had with the Facebook Plugin from nick as well is that when I click the facebook generated Login-link, the screen becomes blank :S

https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=...

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("http://www.google.com");

Shouldn't that do something when I click the link from $helper->getLoginUrl() ?