# Integrating of Facebook SDK as a Vendor to CakePHP

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to integrate Facebook php sdk's current version.I uploaded Facebook SDK to my cakephp vendor folder which is located on `/app/Vendor`.But there exist a some problem on importing files from AppController.I am trying to import Vendor folder but it throws exception . There is a error message on the following segment;

```
Fatal error: Class 'FacebookSession' not found in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/msk_coderank_in/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 41
```

Also, I've tried to `App::import("Vendor","Facebook");` code for importing vendor folders.
The Facebook SDK files located on Facebook folder(For Example: `app/Vendor/Facebook/FacebookSession.php`).

Thanks and Regards

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743655/cakephp-facebooksession-class-not-found-issue**

Comment: Also,I tried it but again it gives Not found output.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Use vendor instead

```
App::uses('Geshi', 'Vendor');
```

Or

```
include APP.'Vendor'.DS.'Facebook'.DS.'FacebookSession.php';
```